# JTable load values on change, display progressbar while loading

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, tablecellrenderer

So i am working with a `JTable`, It has Columns **A-K**. with **A** and **B** being the only editable ones. If someone edits an empty row in **A**, I make an API call to get **B** then i make a DB call to get all rows where **B** exists.If someone edits an empty row in **B**, i make the same call as the will be retrieved from the DB for that row as well. The call returns 0-N rows. If 0 rows were returned, I change the values of all row except **B** to N/A otherwise i populate the rows using the data.Once populated, i make all columns non-editable. The DB call occurs in its own thread as once the call is return i create my own record object which I add to the tablemodel.

I have my own `TableModel` and a `TableModelListener` to keep the data and handle changes in values.

Here is my issue. I am using `TableCellRenderer` and using the *cellrenderer* to see if the value was changed, if so then i make the calls and populate as needed. When a large number of rows is being pulled from DB, it takes a while to load and making all that records so I tried to use a `ProgressBar` to show the user that the screen isn't just frozen, it is progressing and by how much. However the frame that comes up is blank and nothing gets displayed. I get the feeling i am doing something either improperly or missing something.Any help much appreciated.

some code to understand what i am talking about

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTable myTable;
    private MyTableModel tm;
    //OTHER FIELDS

    public static void createPanel() {
           tm = new MyTableModel(columnnames);
           myTable = new JTable(tm);

           TableColumn account = myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(
            MyTableModel.ACCOUNT_INDEX);
    account.setCellRenderer(new MyTableRenderer(
            MyTableModel.ACCOUNT_INDEX));
    }
}

public class MyTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

   protected int interactiveColumn;

   public MyTableRenderer(int interactiveColumn) {
        this.interactiveColumn = interactiveColumn;
    }

   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (column == interactiveColumn && hasFocus) {
             //DO DB and API CALLS HERE
             //IF DB CALL DISPLAY A NEW FRAME WITH PROGRESSBAR
        }
        return c;
   }
}
```

Sorry for formatting issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), which allows you to update your `TableModel` as you examine your result set.

Addendum: Don't try to update the `TableModel` from the renderer. You can update the model when your implementation of `CellEditor` has concluded, by starting a suitable worker in `getCellEditorValue()`. In that way, the revised data will be available when the renderer is next invoked for any modified cell(s). This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513) outlines the approach.

Addendum: `getCellEditorValue()` is invoked after editing has concluded, but starting the worker in `setValueAt()` offers more reliable access to the target row and column.

Comment: hmm, I am sorry, I guess i fail to explain myself clearly. I am using SwingWorker to work with the resultset and create records objects. However I am not adding the record object to the table model in swingworker but in that table cell renderer. When the user loses focus on a column that he just edited, i want to run my command, after some googling, i discovered the above code to do as i wanted. is there some alternate way to get around updating the row on change that you can recommend

Comment: You need a `CellEditor` for that; more above.

Comment: Thanks, I knew my approach wasnt the best, This helps a lot.

Comment: Glad to help; for an overview, I found it helpful to step through the `editingStopped()` method of `JTable` in the debugger.