# change cell color does not work on netbeans

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I created desktop application with Netbeans, and I want to change a particular cell color if it has string value of "on Process".
I tried

```
class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object obj,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (obj=="on Process") {
            cell.setBackground(Color.green);
        } 
        return cell;
    }
}
```

but it is not changing my tableI used

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());
```

I`m getting values from database and using

```
for(int i=0; i<arraylist.size(); i++) {
    table.setValueAt(status, i, 7);
}
```

here status is `String`, if I type manually like:

```
table.setValueAt("on Process", i, 7);
```

it changes the color, it is fine, but I can not type it like that, I need to set value from variable. I tried String, Object, no use!
I tried `toString()`, I tried ""+status, ... it is just ignoring what I assign to it.
Inside forloop if I type "on Process" it works, but outside forloop I can assign from variable, it changes color. I am confused, don`t know what to do.
Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

You need this:

```
if(obj.toString().equals("on Process"))
```

instead of:

```
if(obj=="on Process")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But if I use if(obj.toString().equals("on Process")) It is throwing NullPointerException.

Comment: @user1290988 then use, `if(obj != null && obj.toString().equals("on Process"))`

Answer (score 1):

@Eng.Fouad is right about distinguishing between `equals()` and `==`. You'll also need to verify that your `TableModel` returns the desired [type token](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) for your specified column, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513). The `DefaultTableModel` simply returns `Object.class`.

Comment: columnClasss often is the culprit - shouldn't in this context as the OP is using a per-column renderer. Which might be the problem, if the update from the database triggers a structureChanged. @user1290988, does it?

Comment: @kleopatra is right: `getCellRenderer()` should find the `TableColumn`'s renderer first. A `fireTableStructureChanged()` may cause the "types of the new columns may be different." No change would explain why `setValueAt()` with a `String` literal finds the column renderer.