# Text disappear after Component change size

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, jeditorpane

I create a jTable, and TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor on it. I need to put there editable (with text/html context type) JEditorPane. When i write some text inside and resize component, text disappear. What I doing wrong? Furthermore above this component I have got buttons with text edition: for example:

```
JButton bold = new JButton():
bold.setAction(new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction());
```

It is part of my custom model:

```
private JEditorPane editorTxtPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
private JEditorPane rendererTxtPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
private final JPanel editorPanel = new JPanel();
private final JPanel rendererPanel = new JPanel();
private final ArrayList<FocusListener> editorFocusListeners = new ArrayList<FocusListener>();

public SampleModel() {
    super();

    rendererTxtPane.setContentType("text/html");
    editorTxtPane.setContentType("text/html");

    rendererPanel.add(initCellControls(rendererPanel, rendererLabel));
    rendererPanel.add(rendererTxtPane);

    editorPanel.add(initCellControls(editorPanel, editorLabel));
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(editorTxtPane);
    sp.setBorder(null);
    editorPanel.add(sp);

    editorTxtPane.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            super.focusGained(e);
            e.setSource(editorTxtPane);
            for (int i = editorFocusListeners.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                editorFocusListeners.get(i).focusGained(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            super.focusLost(e);
            e.setSource(editorTxtPane);
            for (int i = editorFocusListeners.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                editorFocusListeners.get(i).focusLost(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It is my editor and renderer methods:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    Comment c = data.get(row);
    rendererTxtPane.setText(c.getComment());
    return rendererPanel;
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    Comment c = data.get(row);
    c.setNeedSave(true);
    editorTxtPane.setText(c.getComment());
    return editorPanel;
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* how [*Editors and Renderers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) work. In particular, the editor is only valid while the cell is being edited. Your `TableModel` should store each row's `Document`. After editing concludes, your model will be updated with the revised `Document`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513). You might compare what your doing with the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513), which could form the basis of your [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This may be the result of one of the two conditions below:

1. The text component that you are embedding in your resisable
   component is being shifted out through the process of resising
   mechanism, so when you are resising it, the inner text component is
   disappearing
2. Whenever the resising process is happening, the standard Swing
   repaint process is not being called by he platform, in the right moment, so you can
   call repaint manually through coding. The SWING platfrom usually
   calls the repaint method automatically whenever it notices a change in
   the overall GUI, but it's schedulled to be run after some other
   processes to complete, in this case calling repaint manually is
   inevitble