# Key Listener for JTable containing JCheckBoxes

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, keylistener

I have a JTable that contains CheckBoxes. My application is built in such a way that whenever any entries are edited, background changes so as to show the entry is in an editing state. I have already set it up with the mouse, but when adding a KeyListener to catch when space is pressed on the keyboard, the keyReleased method only fires when Space has been held for a longer time, and the checkbox selects and deselects rapidly.

When I use the keyTyped and keyPressed methods, all works well except that it is a step behind as in the new data that is entered into the table isn't caught.

So, my question is how can I be able to catch when space is pressed on the table and collect all current values of the table?

I'm using an MVC architecture; here is my Control:

```
public class UserInternalFrameController {

    UserInternalFrame gui = new UserInternalFrame();

    public UserInternalFrameController(ManagementGUI mainGui) {
        gui.getTableUserTransactionPermissions().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("typed");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (e.getKeyChar() == ' ') {
                    if (stateMachine == 2 || stateMachine == 4) {
                        JTable permTable = gui.getTableUserTransactionPermissions();
                        int noOfColumns = gui.getUserTransactionPermissionsHeader().length;
                        permListEdit = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < permList.length; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < noOfColumns; j++) {
                                if (!permList[i][j].equals(permTable.getValueAt(i, j))) {
                                    System.out.println("row" + i + "; column" + j + "; perList:" + permList[i][j] + "; transList: " + permTable.getValueAt(i, j));
                                    permListEdit = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if ((employeeCodeEdit || usernameEdit || passwordEdit || userIdEdit || subjectIdEdit || userStatusEdit || userRoleEdit || permListEdit) == false) {
                            gui.getPanelUser().setBackground(defaultBackgroundPanelUser);
                            gui.getTableUserTransactionPermissions().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                            stateMachine = 2;
                            gui.getBtnSave().setEnabled(false);
                        } else {
                            gui.getPanelUser().setBackground(Color.decode("#f5deb3"));
                            gui.getTableUserTransactionPermissions().setBackground(Color.decode("#f5deb3"));
                            stateMachine = 4;
                            gui.getBtnSave().setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The same block of code works well with a mouse actionListener, and has the same delayed effect when added to the keyPressed method. keyReleased seems to work well with all the other buttons except space.

My keyboard is fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513), and discussed in this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), the default renderer and editor for a table column of type `Boolean.class` is `JCheckBox`. The check box's default mouse handler works correctly, and default [*Key Binding*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) is the <kbd>space</kbd> key. The `UIManager` property `Table.selectionBackground`  will highlight the selected cell in a manner that is preferred by the designer and expected by the user.

I would encourage you to abandon the approach shown and use the defaults.

Comment: Excuse my incompetence. Are you suggesting that I use a TableModelListener to listen for changes to the table? I've tried the following: `gui.getTableUserTransactionPermissions().getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("TableModelListener");
   }
  });` but the tableChanged method never gets called ... which is why I resorted to using mouse and key listeners to begin with.

Comment: The reason why I'm using this approach is because the JTable is in one tab ... details of a record are spread across all tabs. If changes are made on any tab of the record, I want the background of all tabs to be changed so as to notify the user that the record in is an editing state. Also, I'd have to notify my stateMachine (is this a right approach) and enable/disable CRUD buttons.

Comment: Sorry if I implied incompetence; I meant to address mere ignorance, my own included. I can't explain your `TableModelListener` problem; there's an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513). The related tabs should observe the table's model rather than the `JTable` view itself. The `CellEditor` life-cycle is illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513).

Comment: No, my apologies. I was able to solve the problem by using the setDataVector method to populate my TableModel. I was populating my JTables incorrectly (new DefaultTableModel) and so messed up the listener in the process. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Much appreciated!

Comment: Excellent; glad you got it sorted. Don't hesitate to update your question or add an answer, as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the problem was a rather simple one. A novice mistake. This is a snippet of how I was updating my tables on data retrieval (from my controller in MVC pattern; gui is the view instance).

```
// update tableUserSearchResult
gui.setUserSearchTableData(tempList); 
gui.setUserSearchResultTableModel(new DefaultTableModel(
    gui.getUserSearchTableData(), gui.getUserSearchTableHeader()));
gui.getTableUserSearchResult().setModel(gui.getUserSearchResultTableModel());
```

I don't really know why creating a new `DefaultTableModel` instance caused this error, since I define and set the table's model to the newly instance. I suppose that the ...

However, by using the `setDataVector` method of `DefaultTableModel`, I'm able to update the `DefaultTableModel` correctly (without creating) a new instance, and it works just fine:

```
gui.setUserRolePermissionsData(userRolePermissionList);
gui.getUserRolePermissionsTableModel().setDataVector(
    gui.getUserRolePermissionsData(), gui.getUserRolePermissionsHeader());
gui.getTableUserRolePermissions().setModel(gui.getUserRolePermissionsTableModel());
```

This is how I declare the  objects in my view:

```
public class UserRoleInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
DefaultTableModel userRoleDocumentsPermissionsTableModel;
    Object [][] userRoleDocumentsPermissionsData;
    String[] userRoleDocumentsPermissionsHeader = {
        "Document", "Edit", "View", "Process", "Update"
    };
    private JTable tableDocumentPermissions;
    private JScrollPane scrollPaneDocumentPermissions;

...

this.userRolePermissionsTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(
    this.userRolePermissionsData, this.userRolePermissionsHeader);
tableUserRolePermissions = new JTable(this.userRolePermissionsTableModel){
    @Override // in order to render JCheckBox
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        if (c == 1 || c == 2 || c == 3 || c == 4){
            return Boolean.class;
        } else {
            return String.class;
        }
    }
};

scrollPaneEntryTypePermissions.setColumnHeaderView(tableUserRolePermissions);
    scrollPaneEntryTypePermissions.setViewportView(tableUserRolePermissions);
```