# Request editing cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

How to request to edit cell? I added popup menu in DefaultTableModel. And if I click to JMenuItem changename, I would starting editing cell in 2nd row. This row is editable.

Comment: Here is a similar question which should help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838242/start-editing-in-a-cell-in-jtable-on-gaining-focus

Comment: See also [`TablePopupEditor `](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513).

Comment: _I added popup menu in DefaultTableModel_  taken literally, that's **wrong** - you **never** add views to the model ... better show a SSCCE to clarify what you are really doing and what you expect to happen