# SetCaretPosition in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

How can I set caret position in a JTable?

I know JTextField has `setCaretPosition(n)` function. But I cannot access JTextField in the JTable.

I would like the Table text caret position equal text length. It is possible to mouseclick event but it should be normal position.

My code:

```
public class TableTest extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

    public TableTest()
    {
        javax.swing.JTable jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]
                {
                    {
                        "This is too long text!", "This is too long text!",
                    },
                    {
                        "This is too long text!", "This is too long text!",
                    }
                },
                new String[]
                {
                    "Title 1", "Title 2",
                }
        )); 

        add(jTable1);

        pack();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new TableTest().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This table cells are shown:
[This is too...] but it should be [..long text!]

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable / XxxTableModel in local variables, otherwise everything is about pure guessing, hint - question in this form isn't answerable here

Comment: Thanks, i improve my question.

Comment: @mKorbel: Thank you for critical review. Based on the updated question, I've suggested another approach below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This table cells are shown: [This is too...] but it should be [..long text!]

This the renderer that displays the text in a cell. The default renderer is a `JLabel` and it will display `...` when the text is truncated. If you want the `...` at the start of the cell then you need to create a custom renderer.

Check out the [Left Dot Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/left-dot-renderer/) for a renderer that does this.

Answer (score 3):

The default `"startEditing"` action, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11838443/230513), is provided by `BasicTableUI`. It typically selects all the text, which you want to avoid. You can invoke `setCaretPosition()` in a custom `Action` bound to your preferred keystroke. The example below uses the name `"myEditing"` and the <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38051001/230513
 */
public class TableTest {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TableTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
            new String[][]{
                {"This is too long text!", "This is too long text!",},
                {"This is too long text!", "This is too long text!",}
            },
            new String[]{
                "Title 1", "Title 2",}
        ) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return String.class;
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 160);
            }
        };
        table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "myEditing");
        table.getActionMap().put("myEditing", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());
                Component editor = table.getEditorComponent();
                if (editor != null) {
                    editor.requestFocus();
                    if (editor instanceof JTextComponent) {
                        JTextComponent jtc = (JTextComponent) editor;
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                jtc.setCaretPosition(jtc.getDocument().getLength());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        table.putClientProperty("JTable.autoStartsEdit", Boolean.FALSE);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new TableTest()::display);
    }
}
```

For reference, a similar approach for a mouse event is shown in this previous [version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38051001/1).

Comment: I would like to in default position not mouse clicking. Is it possible? All column and row caretposition should be text length.

Comment: I wrote [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11838443/230513) code but nothing changed.

Comment: Based on your [mcve], I've suggested another approach above.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı: Glad you got it sorted. More on how labels work [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3597688/230513).