# Toedter's JDateChooser in JTable column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcalendar, jdatechooser

I'll cut to the chase. I'm try to add Toedter's JDateChooser in a column of a JTable. My app is using MVC pattern, this is from my View:

```
scrollPanePermits = new JScrollPane();
        tableVehiclePermitHeader = new String[] {"Name", "Expiration Date"};
        tableVehiclePermitData = new Object [0][0];
        tableVehiclePermitDefaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(tableVehiclePermitData, tableVehiclePermitHeader);
        tableVehiclePermit = new JTable(tableVehiclePermitDefaultTableModel){
//          public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
//              return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
//           }
            public Class getColumClass(int c){
                if(c == 0){
                    return String.class;
                } else if (c == 1){
                    return JDateChooser.class;
                }
                return null;
            }
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex){
                if (colIndex == 0){
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };
```

I honestly have no way to go about it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it, but you might start with [*Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). Here's a related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513) using `Double` and a [thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/344242/GUI/java/JDateChooser-JTable) about using `JDateChooser`.