# Displaying text (data) from jTable after every Key Stroke using jLabels

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a `JTable` (named `InputTable`) whose cells are editable. When my program will run, I want the user to input data in the cells of the `JTable`. After EVERY KEY STROKE, I want to display the following data :

1. The indices of the row and column of the corresponding cell in which text (data) is being entered
2. The text (data) in the cell currently being edited

I am using 'Netbeans IDE 7.2 RC1'. I have tried the following but the `KeyEvent` is not thrown while editing the cell. When I select a cell and start typing, the cell enters in the editing mode and so the key strokes that follow, after the cell enters in the editing mode, don't generate a `KeyEvent`. And so `inputTableKeyTyped()` method is not called.

```
private void inputTableKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    evt.getKeyChar();
    int row_no = inputTable.getSelectedRow();
    int column_no = inputTable.getSelectedColumn();
    String gottenText = (inputTable.getValueAt(row_no, column_no)).toString();
    jLabel1.setText(gottenText);
    jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(row_no));
    jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(colummn_no));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to a custom [`TableCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513).