# Using TableCellEditor and TableCellRenderer at the same time?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

I am using a TableCellEditor :

```
    package gui.table;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;

import event.TableClickEvent;
import event.TestController;
import gui.DaimlerColor;
import gui.MainWindow;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestcaseCellEditor extends TestcasePanel implements TableCellEditor {

    int row;
    List<String> data;
    TestController tgc;
    transient protected TableClickEvent changeEvent = null;

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public TestcaseCellEditor(final JTable table, MainWindow gui, List<String> data, TestController tgc) {

        super();
        super.gui = gui;
        this.data = data;
        this.tgc = tgc;

        MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                ButtonModel m = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getModel();
                setRow(table.getEditingRow());
                if (m.isPressed() && table.isRowSelected(table.getEditingRow()) && e.isControlDown()) {
                    setBackground(DaimlerColor.LIGHT_BLUE);
                }
            }

        };
        playButton.addMouseListener(ml);

        playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                setRow(table.getEditingRow());
                fireEditingCanceled();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

        this.setToolTipText("Click play to rerun this Testcase");
        this.setName(data.get(row));

        setPlaybuttonIcon(gui.getTestcasetableModelIcon(row));

        setClickable(tgc.clickable);

        if (row <= gui.currentTestcase) {
            Document doc = tgc.getDoc();
            List<Element> cases = doc.getRootElement().getChildren();
            List<Element> teststeps = cases.get(row).getChildren();
            List<String> attributes = new LinkedList<String>();
            for (Element teststep : teststeps) {

                try {
                    if (teststep.getChildren("result").get(gui.sutPaths.getSelectedIndex()).getAttributeValue("status") != null) {
                        attributes.add(teststep.getChildren("result").get(gui.sutPaths.getSelectedIndex())
                                .getAttributeValue("status"));
                    }

                    else {
                        attributes.add("empty");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    attributes.add("empty");
                }

            }

            if (attributes.contains("empty")) {
                setButton("");
            } else if (attributes.contains("failed")) {

                setButton("failed");

            } else {
                setButton("passed");
            }

        } else {
            setButton("");
        }

        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        this.setBackground(isSelected ? DaimlerColor.LIGHT_BLUE : (row % 2 == 1 ? DaimlerColor.DARK_WHITE
                : DaimlerColor.WHITE));

        System.out.println("CLCIKED");

        return this;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelCellEditing() {
        fireEditingCanceled();

    }

    @Override
    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        listenerList.add(CellEditorListener.class, l);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        listenerList.remove(CellEditorListener.class, l);
    }

    public CellEditorListener[] getCellEditorListeners() {
        return listenerList.getListeners(CellEditorListener.class);
    }

    protected void fireEditingStopped() {

        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();

        for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {

            if (listeners[i] == CellEditorListener.class) {

                changeEvent = new TableClickEvent(this.playButton, getRow());
                ((CellEditorListener) listeners[i + 1]).editingStopped(changeEvent);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void fireEditingCanceled() {

        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();

        for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {

            if (listeners[i] == CellEditorListener.class) {

                changeEvent = new TableClickEvent(this, getRow());
                ((CellEditorListener) listeners[i + 1]).editingCanceled(changeEvent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a TableCellrenderer :

```
    package gui.table;

import event.TestController;
import gui.DaimlerColor;
import gui.MainWindow;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestcaseCellRenderer extends TestcasePanel implements TableCellRenderer {

    public List<String> data;
    MainWindow gui = null;
    public TestController tgc = null;

    public TestcaseCellRenderer() {
        super();
        setName("Table.cellRenderer");
    }

    public TestcaseCellRenderer(List<String> names, MainWindow gui2, TestController tgc) {
        super();
        this.data = names;
        this.gui = gui2;
        this.tgc = tgc;
        setName("Table.cellRenderer");
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {

        this.setToolTipText("Click play to rerun this Testcase");
        System.out.println("Rendering your ass!");
        this.setName(data.get(row));
        setPlaybuttonIcon(gui.getTestcasetableModelIcon(row));
        setClickable(tgc.clickable);

        if (row <= gui.currentTestcase) {
            Document doc = tgc.getDoc();
            List<Element> cases = doc.getRootElement().getChildren();
            List<Element> teststeps = cases.get(row).getChildren();
            List<String> attributes = new LinkedList<String>();
            for (Element teststep : teststeps) {

                try {
                    if (teststep.getChildren("result").get(gui.sutPaths.getSelectedIndex()).getAttributeValue("status") != null) {
                        attributes.add(teststep.getChildren("result").get(gui.sutPaths.getSelectedIndex())
                                .getAttributeValue("status"));
                    }

                    else {
                        attributes.add("empty");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    attributes.add("empty");
                }

            }

            if (attributes.contains("empty")) {
                setButton("");
            } else if (attributes.contains("failed")) {

                setButton("failed");

            } else {
                setButton("passed");
            }

        } else {
            setButton("");
        }

        if (tgc.isRerunning() && tgc.getEventRow() == row) {
            setButton("");
        }

        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        this.setBackground(isSelected ? DaimlerColor.LIGHT_BLUE : (row % 2 == 1 ? DaimlerColor.DARK_WHITE
                : DaimlerColor.WHITE));

        return this;
    }

}
```

Somehow if I click on the text in the table it only sets the focus every second click? It also only fires the fireEdizingCanceled Event every second time? Why is that?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> Somehow if I click on the text in the table it only sets the focus
>   every second click? Why is that?

- right this is default value for  `XxxTableCellEditor` invoked from `MouseEvents`
- you can to change `myEditor.setClickCountToStart(1);`
- `XxxCellRenderer` is invoked from all `Mouse`, `Key` and internal methods implemented in API, you testing strange things inside `Renderer` (`Editor` too), lools like as quite hard job, can caused freeze of repaints, and refresh of cell is done only on mouse_over_hover

EDIT

> Where do I need to call that? My TableCellEditor doesn´t have this
>   method.

pseudocode

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(......); // abstract or custom name 
editor.setClickCountToStart(2); // for Compound JComponents (JComboBox) is more userfriendly invoke Editor on second click
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(editor);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Where do I need to call that? My TableCellEditor doesn´t have this method.

Comment: Hi, I need to Use the TableCellEditor because I have a JButton in my Table Row which also fires Events. I can´t cast to DefaultTableModel.

Comment: @HansEn: See also this complete, working [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513).

Comment: Thanks fpr the example. I just somwhow need to get rid of this double click feature. The strange thing is, if I click on the JPanel somewhere it calls the method every time, if I click on a JLabel, it only works every second time. Why is that?