# Jtable with protected and selectable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextcomponent

How to make a JTable cells selectable while they are set non editable.
when i doubkle click  at the moment its not selecting the cells. while want it to slecet the cell so that can be copied by contorl  c .

Comment: setEnabled? setEditable?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for a way to `selectAll()` in the cell editor's text component. The approach cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513) works for `F2` or a `MouseEvent`.