# Format JTable column for currency

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, currency-formatting

I have a `JTable` and I want a particular column to formatted as currency. If i put a number on that column like 3 it will show $3.00. i used `TableCellRenderer` but i'm not getting into it. Can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  Showing your effort will encourage others to help.

Comment: like i have mentioned i used the `TableCellRenderer`

Comment: See also [`CurrencyRenderer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/).

It shows how to use a renderer to do simple formatting by using the `Format` class. It even supports a convenience method for formatting currencies.

By the way in the last two questions that you posted and accepted an answer, there were better (simpler) answers that you could have used.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example. I don't know whether it works (if not - try to fix it).

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
public class CurrencyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private static final NumberFormat FORMAT = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    @Override
    public final Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        final Component result = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (value instanceof Number) {
            setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
            setText(FORMAT.format(value));
        } else {
            setText("");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

To add it:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setCellRenderer(new CurrencyTableCellRenderer());
```

Comment: i tried your code but it's give me errors like can not find symbol `getTableCellRendererComponent` for the line `final Component result = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);`

Comment: I've added the import statements. Now it must compile.

Comment: well it did compile !! but after tabbing out the cell the data is just vanished.

Comment: Sorry, but nobody can find all your bugs without to have the code. So you should do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

/**
 * Created by Ayettey on 06/02/2017.
*/
public class  CurrencyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

CurrencyRenderer(){
    super();

}

public void setValue(Object value){

    Number number=(Number)value;
      if((value!=null)&&(value instanceof Number)){
          NumberFormat numberFormat=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
          value=numberFormat.format(number.doubleValue());
      }



    super.setValue(value);

}

}
```

Comment: TableColumnModel model=table.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn tableColumn=model.getColumn(t.ACCOUNT_BALANCE);
        tableColumn.setCellRenderer(new CurrencyRenderer());

Comment: First of all, could you please explain *how* and *why* this solves the OPs question? And *please note*, that there is an **edit** function for answers, questions, and the like. If you want to extend your answer, please edit it and do not mis-use the comments as an edit.