# Why are there two different editing modes with DefaultCellEditors?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

When using a DefaultCellEditor in a JTable, there seem to be two different editing modes:

- Single clicking on a cell does not display the editor component, but (for String/Object classes) one can still type in the selected cell and thereby edit its value.
- Double clicking on a cell displays the editor component and one can edit the selected cell's value as expected.

Why is this? One would think that editing a JTable cell's value would always involve the same UI behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, double clicking a cell and typing in a cell (which supports text editing) essentially boils down to the same thing.  You can actually double click a text editable cell to start the editing process

Cell editability comes to down to two factors, the result of [`TableModel#isCellEditable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29) and [`TableCellEditor#isCellEditable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#isCellEditable%28java.util.EventObject%29), when these two methods return `true` a cell can be placed into edit mode.

A text editable cell is, generally, a special case, where the cell can be edited by typing in the cell while it has focus and double clicking (and pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> in most cases).

The case for providing more than one mechanism for initializing the editing process will come down to decisions made over usability and existing conventions across multiple platforms.  It's likely that some attempt was made to mix expectations where possible so users of different platforms could feel more comfortable with the process, but this is simply speculation.

The problem is, even amongst users of a single platform, there are different expectations about how something like this works, so rather the supply a single trigger, the system has been designed to allow for multiple triggers, where it would be applicable.

For example, it wouldn't make sense for a cell containing an image to allow the user to edit the cell simply by typing in it.

**Updated**

If you take a look at the `isCellEdtiable` method for `DefaultCellEditor`...

```
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
    if (anEvent instanceof MouseEvent) {
        return ((MouseEvent)anEvent).getClickCount() >= clickCountToStart;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You will note that the only event that actually stops a cell from entering edit mode is a `MouseEvent`, but only when the number of mouse clicks is less than `clickCountToStart`, which is set to `2` when using a `JTextField` as the editor, otherwise it's `1`

Comment: My confusion is over a JTable cell - using a DefaultCellEditor with a JTextField as the editor component - being editable when single-clicked but without actually using the editor component. Does that make sense?

Comment: I would think that has more to do with how the table switches between render mode and edit mode

Comment: See also the approach described by camickr in an article cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513).

Comment: @MadProgrammer From what I can tell, `DefaultCellEditor.isCellEditable()` returns false when a JTable cell is single-clicked. Nevertheless, if I start typing in the selected (via single-click) cell, its value changes. I'm still confused as to why that is. It seems to break the notion of a clean separation between editing and rendering modes.

Comment: Why is a `KeyEvent` for a editor that supports a text value consider bad?

Comment: Consider the update. As I said, you're asking a question about a design decision that was made more the 15 years ago was probably made based on expectations of the time and user expectations across multiple platforms. The distinction between a renderer value and and editable value is probably mute from the perspective of a user. Either they can edit it or they can't...

Comment: That's my point. The editor component isn't actually displayed for a cell that's simply been selected (i.e. by a single click) - at least with `DefaultCellEditor`. But the selected cell can still be edited.

Comment: So how does that change for a double click?  The cell is still selected on a single click, but if you double click, it's editable?

Comment: In the sense of "editable" as "typing changes the cell's value", the cell is "editable" when both single-clicked and double-clicked. In the sense of "editable" as "the cell's editor is displayed", the cell is "editable" only when double-clicked. Does that make sense?

Comment: The editor is available in either case on a single click.  It only becomes available when both `TableModel#isCellEditable` and `TableCellEditor#isCellEditable` are true. A cell is "always" editable when `TableModel#isCellEditable` is `true`, but will only enter edit mode when `TableCellEditor#isCellEditable` is `true`.  So, for example, if you are using the arrow keys to navigate through the cells, they won't "suddenly" become editable, because the navigation keys are "special", but if you type, press [enter] or [F2], then the cell will enter edit mode...does that make sense?

Comment: So when `TableModel#isCellEditable` is `true` but `TableCellEditor#isCellEditable` is `false`, the cell is editable but the editor component isn't displayed? Then what component _is_ being displayed to edit the cell with? Logically (to me, at least), it should be the editor component, but it isn't.

Comment: *"So when `TableModel#isCellEditable` is `true` but `TableCellEditor#isCellEditable` is `false`, the cell is editable but the editor component isn't displayed?"* - Yes, the cell renderer is still being displayed, because the cell is editable/in edit mode

Comment: I guess that's what baffles me. I'd assume that, when changing an editable cell's value, the editor component would always be displayed. So why isn't it?

Comment: You're mixing up your states. When selected, the cell is "rendered", when a editable event trigger is detected, the the editor component is displayed and the state is switched to editing

Comment: If I select a cell (by single-clicking it) and then start typing, the cell's value changes according to what I type. _However,_ I don't believe the editor component is displayed in that situation. For one thing, the text caret does not appear. Furthermore, the background and border don't change, whereas they do when the editor component (a JTextField) is displayed. So no, I don't believe I'm mixing up my states.

Comment: Yes it is...You could test this by changing the `JTextField`'s background color to something that the renderer doesn't ues. I believe the behaviour you've descrieved can be changed by setting the tables `surrendersFocusOnKeystroke` to `true` using `JTable#setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(boolean surrendersFocusOnKeystroke)`.  In order to edit a cell, a editor component MUST be invoked, it can't be edited in any other way...

Comment: Okay, I performed the test that you suggested, and I was surprised to see the selected cell's background color change when I started typing in it. So you're correct - in order to edit a cell, an editor component must be invoked. That does make a lot more logical sense. However, I'm still wondering why the caret doesn't appear.

Comment: It has to do with how focus is transferred between the table and editor, see the surrndersFocusOnKeystroke property