# Java jTable sort percentage values not working

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I was wondering why my jTable is not sorting percentage values and how I can fix this?
I was hoping that I could convert the whole row into a string but that still doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

```
package tables;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
public class mainwindow extends JPanel
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static Object data[][];
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DecimalFormat round = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
    testFrame.setTitle("table");
    testFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    data = new Object[30][3];
    String test = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i ++)
    {
            test = (String) (round.format(100 * new Double((double)  i / 9)))+ "%"; //     dummy values
        data[i][0] = test;
        data[i][1] = "a";
        data[i][2] =  "a";
    }
    Object[] columns =
    {"Track #", "Title", "Length"};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columns)
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    };
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    testFrame.add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    testFrame.pack();
    testFrame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: it should be works, start with / when you remove casting to String - (String) (round.format

Comment: What do you mean? What should I change  

test =  (String) (round.format(100 * new Double((double)  i / 9)))+ "%"; // dummy values 

to?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)` means that a RowSorter will be created when the table's model is changed (it's in the JavaDoc!). Since the model is never changed, a RowSorter is not created. Add a call to `table.setModel(model)` after `table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)`.

You need to tell the table that its data are Double objects, not Strings - because you want to sort them like Doubles and only display them as Strings.

Set the data in the array to a Double object:

```
data[i][0] = new Double(i);
```

And edit the table model thus:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
        if (col == 0) {
            return Double.class;
        }
        return String.class;
    }

};
```

And now implement a custom cell renderer for the first column:

```
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    class PercentRenderer extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable itable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JLabel oLabel = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(itable, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (value instanceof Double) {
                oLabel.setText(round.format(100. * (double) value) + "%");
            }
            return oLabel;
        }
    }
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new PercentRenderer());
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing a `String` in your `TableModel`, store a `Double`. Use a [custom renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) to format the value as a percent, as shown in this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513). Instead of

```
private NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

use

```
private NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
```

In this way, your `RowSorter` can rely on the natural sort order of `Double`.