# JCombobox with custom DefaultListCellRenderer as a DefaultCellEditor: returns string value instead of custom object

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, listcellrenderer

I have a `JTable` with a model that implements `AbstractTableModel`. The Model holds custom `RequisitionItem` objects which also have a `Section` Object in one of its field. When inserting a new record into the table, i add a new row with a new `RequisitionItem` initialized with non-null but empty values. For the `Section` column, i have custom renderers for the table and the combobox as follows

for the table;

```
requestItemsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
            public void setValue(Object value) {
                if (value==null) {
                    setText("");
                } else {
                    Section section = (Section) value;
                    setText(section.getName());
                }

            }});
```

for the combobox;

```
   sectionComboBox.setRenderer(new BasicComboBoxRenderer() {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (value != null) {

                setText(((Section) value).getName());
            }
            if (index == -1) {

                setText("");
            }
            return this;
        }

    });
```

for the editing, i have the following;

```
sectionComboBox = new JComboBox<>();
sectionComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(sectionJpaController.getDepartmentSections(department.getNumber()).toArray(new Section[0])));
requestItemsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(sectionComboBox));
```

But after clicking the `Section` cell, selecting one of the `Section` items in the combobox and hitting enter, i get `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to ***.model.domain.Section`. Sow why is the return from the `DefaultCellEditor` not a section object but String?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe. You might get some ideas from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513).

Comment: As an aside, I've not seen this usage of `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer`; can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to use so much customized logic for rendering and selecting your Section objects in the combobox?

If I understand correctly, you are trying to render only the name your Section objects on the JCombobox but be able to retrieve the entire Section object at the JTable.

To achieve this, you only need to things:

1. Initialize the JComboBox using a vector of Section objects that are for selection.
2. return the name of Section in its toString method because JComboBox evaluates the toString of its items for rendering.
3. set the combox to be used in the CellEditor for the JTable column for Section (which you have done)

A running example would be:

```
public class JTableWithComboboxEditor extends JFrame {
class Section {
    String name;
    int value2;

    public Section(String name, int value2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

private JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Section"}, 2));


public JTableWithComboboxEditor() {
    this.add(new JScrollPane(table));

    Section section1 = new Section("A", 1);
    Section section2 = new Section("B", 2);
    Vector sectionList = new Vector();
    sectionList.add(section1);
    sectionList.add(section2);

    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(sectionList);

    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            Object value = table.getValueAt(0, 0);
            if (value != null) {
                Section section = (Section) value;
                System.out.println(section.name + " " + section.value2);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```