# TableCellEditor: clear original text if key is pressed; retain value if no input was givien

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, tablecelleditor

I have here a code I found in the stackoverflow which allows the table to have a custom cell editor as `JTextField`.

I have been reading some of the articles about cell editor and I understand some the behavior of each abstract method.

```
class tableText extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
JComponent component = new JTextField();

public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
    ((JTextField) component).setText((String) value);
    return component;
}

public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return ((JTextField) component).getText();
}
```

}

This code allowed me to add a `JTextField` when I want to edit a cell in my table but I am looking to add some code to it but Im not exactly sure where to put them.

The behavior I wanted to add was this:

When the cell is clicked and the `JTextField` appears, if the user pressed a numerical key, it will replace the old value with a new one.

If the cell's value was left blank, the original value will be retained.

I know how to make these codes, but I'm not sure where to put them.

Anyone can guide me on this?

Comment: Please cite the example code mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > If the user pressed a numeric key, it will replace the old value with a new one.

   As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513), you should use a `DefaultCellEditor` with a `JTextField` for your cell editor. Override the table's `editCellAt()` method and select the editor's text so that the old value will be replaced immediately as the user types.

   ```
   final Component editor = getEditorComponent();
   …
   ((JTextComponent) editor).selectAll();
   ```

   If necessary, add a [`DocumentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to examine individual keystrokes or a [`DocumentFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) to enforce numeric entry.
2. > If the cell's value was left blank, the original value will be retained.

   Press the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key to cancel editing and restore the original value.

[image]

Comment: It actually took me a long time to learn `TableCellEditor` and `TableCellRenderer`. these were like alien language to me back then but now it makes total sense!