# Use determined characters in a column of a jTable

Tags: java, jtable, string-formatting

I need a method that allows only certain characters are entered in a jTable.

My jframe is below:

[image]

In the columnd "Precedentes" i need that the column accepts only numbers and ",".

A input example that i need:

[image]

My validation method of this column is below:

```
private void jTable1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                
            i = 0; 
            String carac="0987654321,";
            if(!carac.contains(tableModel.getValueAt(i, 3)+"")){
            tableModel.consume();// TODO add your handling code here:
            }
}
```

i => It's my line number (it's used in a loop to verify each line).
So I go line line by line getting what the user typed in the column "precedentes" and validate with that method.

When i type something that is not a number or "," the columns "Precedente" should not accept.

Error message when i execute my method:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I think what i need is a mask that accepts only number and ",", but i don't know how to do this to a column of a jTable, i know how to to this with a text field, but the method that i use to validate that in a text field doesn't work in a jtable.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [*How to Use Tables: Using an Editor to Validate User-Entered Text*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext), you can override the `DefaultCellEditor` method `stopCellEditing()` to check whether the text is valid. The `CellEditor` seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539298/230513) is an example for model values of type `Integer`. For values of type `Date`, you can use `JFormattedTextField` in your `CellEditor`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2511415/230513), and you can validate dates using `SimpleDateFormat`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2241997/230513). To validate individual characters, construct your `JFormattedTextField` with a [`MaskFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#maskformatter), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2511415/230513).

Comment: I want that when the user type something that not be number or "," in a columng of the jtable, the programa doesn't accept (don't allow to write in the table of jframe) , I can do that integrating this Two methods above ?

Comment: You might look at [`MaskFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#maskformatter), a `DocumentListener` to examine individual keystrokes or a `DocumentFilter` to enforce numeric entry, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37878422/230513).

Comment: I've updated the original post with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'd start with a `MaskFormatter` for your `JFormattedTextField` in your `CellEditor`; please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your chosen approach.

Comment: I believe now it'a easier to understand my doubt. I've updated to the MCV.

Comment: What do you need more? I believe with that you can understood my problem, like i said before, i need that the column "precedentes" accept only Numbers and ",", i am using the method above to validate that, but when i type something like 20,30,a,50 in the column "precedentes" i need that my method of validation do not accept nothinng more than Numbers and ",", In the example above the letter "a" should not appear in the column when i type it.  Sorry about my doubt, i started programming java 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Without your [mcve], I don't know where you're stuck. If you're in a hurry, try [tag:jcalendar], seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14880675/230513).

Comment: I added a photo and improved my explanation of my problem. Now I believe that you will understand my question and understand my validation method that is not working .

Comment: I see the kind of problem you're trying to solve, but I don't see where your `MaskFormatter` fails.

Comment: I edited the post again, i put my entire method of validation, and the error that appears when i execute. In addition to the error happens the method does not work because when I press a button other than number or "," the column still accepts, the correct thing is when I press a button that is not number or  ", " the column doesn't show .